# ZFS modules are not loaded after kernel update

Tags: 14.04, zfs

I have been running ZFS on 14.04 for a little over a year now and so far everything has been running and updating perfectly.

Today after `apt-get update` I see that I know have kernel 4.4.0-59-generic (updated from 3.19.0-78-generic). I recall there was a long delay during the update but everything appeared fine in the end. I did a reboot and left the house for a few hours. Now that I have logged back in I see that my zfs pool is missing.

So I run the `zfs list` command and I get the message `The ZFS modules are not loaded. Try running ‘/sbin/modprobe zfs’`. So I try, same message `the ZFS modules are not loaded`.

So here is my question: Should I try rolling back to the previous kernel or should I just reinstall the zfs modules? I don’t want to make the wrong move as I am worried I could lose my 4.5TB pool.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I went back and booted kernel 3.19.0-78 from the grub boot menu and my zpool is there and healthy which is a relief. I guess now I’m not sure how to proceed as this is only a temp solution, I assume Ubuntu will load the 4.4.0 kernel anytime I reboot without my manually selecting the old kernel. Will I need to upgrade to 16.04 in order to have support on the 4.4.0 kernel. I’ve been looking at doing this however I’ve not yet had a chance to test the upgrade process.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the version of ZFS available in the Ubuntu repositories does not compile with the latest kernel, which seems like an unfortunate oversight to me. Until ZFS is either updated to version 0.6.5.8 or the patch is backported, it won't work with this kernel, and you'll need to continue booting an older one.

Source: https://github.com/zfsonlinux/pkg-zfs/issues/219

Note that you can edit the GRUB configuration to save which kernel you last booted from and always boot from that one until you tell it otherwise.

EDIT: I'm actually on 16.04, but I'm getting the same error as that bug report, so presumably this issue affects both versions.

Comment: Update came down today to zfsutils 0.6.5.8. Zpool is now loading on the updated kernel. cheers!

Comment: Well, it doesn't appear to have made it to the main Ubuntu repos for 16.04, unfortunately. I'm surprised they've left it completely broken for so long in an LTS release. (I'm using both ZFS and kernel from the main Ubuntu repos, no PPAs.)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue when using the mintupgrade from 17.3 -> 18 (trusty -> xenial), during the upgrade process a package I had messed with caused the upgrade to partially fail so when upgrading from 3.X kernel to 4.4.0-81-generic it didn't properly rebuild everything, it took me a while to figure out why the zfspool had a status of online and looked fine but did not show up in df and did not work despite the fact it was mounted at a location that still existed, I had to ask dpkg to rebuild them for 4.4.0:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure spl-dkms
sudo dpkg-reconfigure zfs-dkms
sudo zpool import zfspoolname
```